# Volume of revolution help!

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, definite-integrals

say we wanted to calculate the volume of the solid of revolution of the region bound by

$y=x^{2}-2 , y=0$ , about $y=-1$ ( but only consider the part above $y=-1$)

I have been wondering it for a while almost two weeks. Could someone please just take a few minutes for it? Please? I am desperately wanting to find the correct answer ASAP. I think maybe none of the above are correct. It could be done by any method at all

Comment: are you asking about how to solve this problem using double integrals (which seems like overkill to me) or about typical volumes of revolution?

Comment: @AndresMejia Well, I am asking about this specific example in general. But also I am curious if anyone has input on the other aspect about solving via double integral. But it does not need to be done that way

Comment: From -1 to 1, consider the fact that $x^2-2 \leq -1$. Sorry, I am not at a computer

Answer (score 1):

Double integrals can be used sometimes, maybe in the case of "easier" functions, like $z=9-x^2-y^2$, which is going to be a circle for every horizontal slice, but a bunch of parabolas when you take a vertical slice. You could easily solve for the volume enclosed by this parabloid and the x-y plane with a double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3} (9-r^2)r\cdot drd\theta$$

or alternatively:

$$\int \int_{R} 9-x^2-y^2dxdy$$

But a cleaner kind of solution might be with familiar methods:

As another way to think about it, this is just a parabola $y=9-x^2$ being revolved around the y-axis

$$\int_{0}^{9}\pi x^2dy$$
$$=\int_{0}^{9}\pi \sqrt((9-y))^2dy$$

An even different solution is to take the first expression and notice that $dy/dx=-2x$, so $dy=-2xdx$ and use this substitution instead.

So: $$\int_{0}^{9}\pi x^2dy$$

=$$\int_{3}^{0}\pi x^2(-2x)dx$$

(you just have to change the bounds on the definite integral to 3 by solving $9-x^2=0$, and swap them to get a positive value.

All of these methods are the same, it depends on how you look at them. The trouble with double integrals is that you need a clean expression for the volume of revolution, but there are always a number of ways to tackle a problem, especially once your toolset for multivariable calculus expands. With this, can you solve the specific problem, or should I also give an explicit solution for it?

---

Your problem: First, just for "cleanliness" I'll change it slightly so that it is: $y=x^2-1$ being revolved around $y=0$ and bounded above by $y=1$.
Notice that the parabola actually intersects $y=0$. It might be easiest to solve this by slicing it up into 3 different pieces, two of which are symmetric (for visualization purposes:

$$2 \cdot \int_{-\sqrt(2)}^{-1} \pi \cdot (x^2-1)^2dx+\int_{-1}^{1}\pi \cdot (x^2-1)^2dx=4.14$$

But this is just for a visualization purpose. You can go ahead and solve this problem more straightforwardly: (by just integrating in one whole piece.)

As for double integrals, you can use the above method and simply write out the double integral, although this really seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I understand that part , I am more interested in my actual example

Comment: Oh!, I'm sorry, give me one second

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for getting me thinking. Yea I see now breaking up into 3 is probably the best bet. Also on making it so your just around y=0 helps, but what would the form be if we wanted to keep it as y=-1 rotating around y=-1?

Comment: in your last sentence, do you mean keep it as $y=0$ rotated around $y=-1$?

Comment: yes that is what I meant

Comment: All of the math is the same, it's just easier to look at it when we talk about axed we are used to. For instance: instead of solving for $\sqrt(2)$ by solving $x^2-1=1$, you would just instead solve $x^2-2=0$, an equivalent statement. when you solved for your so-called "radius of revolution", you would just want the difference between the curve and y=-1, so you would go: $r=(x^2-2)-(-1)=x^2-1$. Nothing fancy, it just eliminates some algebra to adjust "Where" on the cartesian plane you want to revolve around.

Comment: I thank you for your time, but I am still actually wanting to know spefically how it could be solved using double integrals, regardless of if it is overkill or not

Comment: Also how does this account for that we are only considering the part above y=-1??

Comment: I didnt see that in the original problem, you delete the middle part of the integral, so the second part of the sum is ignored

Comment: Can you explain that?